# Xcode 11 beta 5 - Unsupported Xcode error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload to Testflight but I receive this error while uploading the archive, any workaround?

> ERROR ITMS-90744: "Unsupported Xcode or SDK Version. Your app was
>   built with a version of Xcode or SDK that is not yet supported for
>   upload to App Store Connect. For more information about supported
>   versions of Xcode and SDK for Testflight or App Store submissions,
>   view the App Store Connect What's New page
>   (https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/)."

Comment: can you tell the XCode version and the minimum iOS version you are setting for the application?

Comment: You can't upload with beta version until it goes GM. That will probably will take a few more months.

Comment: Seems like apple doesn't support new applications thats build with New Xcode. I think we should wait for stable release.

Comment: According to the link in your question, beta 4 is supported but there is no announcement yet regarding beta 5.  Try beta 4 or wait for an announcement on beta 5

Comment: Thats new. Didn't notice we could upload before GM seed.

Comment: I ended up downgrading to Xcode 10.3 in order to deploy a build

Comment: Downgrade to Xcode 10.3 is not possible if you've made any changes in Xcode 11 to the Storyboard.